File upload using angular 18 and .net 8
I am trying to upload a file from angular app to c# Web API (essentially to aws s3 bucket through service) with no success, I could use postman to upload files to API which seems to see the filenames in the controller but with Angualar app I always get no files count.
In the network tab and in console I can see form data is posted in request but I don't see anything coming in Controller.
Question: does the file have to be encoded with base 64 and send to API and write the content back into s3?
or can use form-data to post the file to API and save in s3?
Here the code for angular18 and .NET8
upload.component.html:
          <div class="card mb-4">
            <div class="card-header">
              <strong>Upload</strong>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="upload-section mb-3">
                          <label for="fileUpload" class="form-label">Select File</label>
                          <input
                            type="file"
                            id="fileUpload"
                            (change)="onFileSelected($event)"
                            class="form-control"
                            multiple
                          />
                        </div>
                          <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
                          <button
                            type="button"
                            class="btn btn-primary me-2"
                            (click)="uploadDocuments()"
                          >
                            Upload
                          </button>
                          <button
                            type="button"
                            class="btn btn-secondary"
                            (click)="resetDocuments()"
                          >
                            Reset
                          </button>
                        </div>
            </div>
          </div>

upload.component.ts
  onFileSelected(event: any) {
  if (event.target.files && event.target.files.length > 0) {
    const files: FileList = event.target.files;
    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      this.selectedDocuments.push(files[i]);
    }
  }
}

  uploadDocuments() {
  if (this.selectedDocuments.length > 0) {
    this.uploadProgress = 0; // Reset progress
    this.documentService.uploadDocuments(this.selectedDocuments).subscribe({
      next: (event) => {
        if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress && event.total) {
          this.uploadProgress = Math.round((100 * event.loaded) / event.total);
        } else if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
          console.log('Documents uploaded successfully:', event.body);
          alert('Documents uploaded successfully!');
          this.selectedDocuments = []; // Clear the list after uploading
          this.uploadProgress = 0; // Reset progress
        }
      },
      error: (error) => {
        console.error('Error uploading documents:', error);
        alert('An error occurred during document upload.');
      }
    });
  } else {
    alert('There are no documents selected for upload.');
  }
}

upload.service.ts
uploadDocuments(files: File[]): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const formData = new FormData();
    files.forEach(file => {
      formData.append('files', file, file.name);
});
console.log('FormData:', formData); // Just to check the formData contents

formData.forEach((value, key) => {
  console.log(`Key: ${key}, Value:`, value);
});
console.log('FormData size:', formData.getAll('files').length);


const req = new HttpRequest('POST', `${this.apiUrl}/documents/upload`, formData, {
  reportProgress: true,  // Enable progress tracking
  responseType: 'json'
});

return this.http.request(req).pipe(
  catchError(this.handleError) // Handle errors properly
);

}
Controller:
      [HttpPost("upload"), DisableRequestSizeLimit]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadDocuments([FromForm] IFormFileCollection files)
    {
        if (files.Count == 0)
        {
            return BadRequest("No files selected.");
        }
        await _documentService.UploadDocumentsAsync(files, GetOrganizationName());
        return Ok("Files uploaded successfully.");
    }

